# Is it possible to produce a probability/likelihood that an observation belongs to a particular dataset using kNN?

Tags: python, classification, knn

I'm aware that kNN clustering can be used to identify what group an unlabelled observation belongs to by using the euclidean distance between that observation and the closest k labelled ones.

My question is can we do this but for datasets?
For example, say you have a dataset df and you want to compare another dataset df2 (or multiple: df3, df4 etc) with the observations of df.

My idea at the moment is to concatenate all the datasets together:

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df,df1,df2,df3,..],axis = 1)
```

and create a variable `df_concat['flag'] = 1` for the obs in df and `df_concat['flag'] = 0` for observations from the other datasets.
I can then train the model using this engineered column as y.
However the kNN classifier only outputs an array of 1s and 0s of whether the observations would be in df or not rather than a probability or the distance of that observation from this dataset.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this or another method that would work for what I'm trying to do?